# How to get context of docusign envelope timezone or get Zulu time from api?

Tags: docusignapi

I am aware we can set our docusign timezone from the account settings panel, but is there a way to do it pragmatically?

The problem I'm facing is that we have servers and signers in different timezones and I'm using docusign connect. Because docusign connect and my service doesn't guarantee in order delivery, I only update the state of our docusign object with the latest docusign connect object. However, I noticed that my naïve time check doesn't work because in the context of our different accounts we don't guarantee which timezone the envelope is from.

One way I can do it is ignore all older changes based on status. E.g. Created -> Sent -> Signed -> Completed

Answer (score 0):

In the root of the connect object there's two parameters

```
"TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
 "TimeZoneOffset": "-7"
```

To convert the time given in javascript to a standard ISO time, we can use
`Date.parse(docusign.time+"-07:00")`